# Simplifying Combinatorial Expression

Tags: combinatorics

Let 
\begin{equation}
B(n,w) = \sum_{y=0}^{v-1}2^{2v+1 - 2y}\binom{v-1}{y} \binom{n-v}{v-y} + \sum_{y=0}^{v-2}2^{2v-1 - 2y}\binom{v-1}{y} \binom{n-v-1}{v-y-2},
\end{equation}
where $v=\min(w,n-w)$.

The way this is constructed, $\sum_{w=0}^n B(n,w) = 4\times 3^{n-1}$. Can someone help in simplifying the expression for $B(n,w)$ for $0\le w\le n$?

Comment: I doubt that you'll find something. What you need is basically [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity),

$$
{m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}\;,
$$

but with a factor $q^k$ included; I'm not aware of a closed form for that. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum+of+binom+%28m,k%29+*+binom+%28n,r-k%29+*+q^k++for+k%3D0..r) expresses this in terms of the hypergeometric function.